# Select every element between two ids

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-selectors

[**Update:** As the problem does *not seems to be solvable using CSS only*, a **JavaScript** function using the two marked elements as input would suffice]

I have a recursive list with two elements marked by IDs (`T1`, `T2`).
The two elements are not necessarily siblings of each other.

My question regards a **CSS selector** to select every `li` list item **between** those two IDs:

- including:

  - the element with the IDs themselves
  - all `li` child or parent nodes that are in between those two (recursively), not just siblings
- (excluding

  - all elements before the first id or after the second id
  - all non-`li` elements)

The ids `T1` and `T2` could also be in different order, with `T2` coming first and `T1` somewhere later in the tree.

---

The example below shows the two ID elements together with the elements that should be selected:

```css
#T1 { color: red;}
#T2 { color: blue;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>not selected</li>
  <li>not selected</li>
  <ul>
    <li>not selected</li>
    <li id="T1">selected (specific id)</li>
    <li>selected</li>
    <ul>
      <li>selected</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>selected</li>
    <li>selected</li>
    <ul>
      <li>selected</li>
      <li>selected</li>
      <li id="T2">selected (specific id)</li>
    </ul>
    <li>not selected</li>
  </ul>
  <li>not selected</li>
  <li>not selected</li>
  <ul>
    <li>not selected</li>
  </ul>
  <li>not selected</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well there is not a simple solution because they are not siblings....

Comment: Not possible with CSS because there are no previous sibling or parent selectors, both of which would be necessary in order to exclude and include elements.

Comment: JavaScript. I don't see how CSS can do that.

Comment: I updated the question asking for a CSS or JavaScript solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that takes an array of elements, loops through them, and applies a specific class to all elements in between the two ids (and also including the elements with the ids).

```
var liElements = document.querySelectorAll("li");

var selectElementsBetweenIds = function (elements, id1, id2) {

  var firstIdFound = false;
  var applySelector = false;


  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var elementId = elements[i].getAttribute("id");

    if (elementId === id1 || elementId === id2) {
      applySelector = firstIdFound ? false : true;
      firstIdFound = applySelector ? true: false;
      elements[i].classList.add("selected");
      continue;
    }
    if (applySelector) {
      console.log("getting here");
      elements[i].classList.add("selected");
    }
  }
}

selectElementsBetweenIds(liElements, "T2", "T1");
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zh5s7223/)

Comment: Small edge case: if both ids are on the same element, all elements behind that element will get selected, not just the element itself.

Comment: @StefanRamson Is this a case that your solution will need to include? With a minor addition this could be accounted for. What would be the expected behavior of this case? Select the one element and be done?

Comment: Exactly, in this case just one element should be selected. However, I realized that the edge case does not make sense in context of the question (as one element can only have a single id). In our application, we have direct references to the marked elements. Anyway, thanks.